# Mule - connection to db is failing

Tags: java, database, maven, timeout, mule

I have a mule application that I can deploy on the server, but when I try to run a request (I'm using postman for this) I keep getting a timeout on a db query. I'm not sure what's causing the connection issue - the db is up and running and I can easily access it through IntelliJ. Running the query on the db (that fails when running from mule) gives instant results.

Does anyone know what I might be missing? I'm using mule standalone v3.9.3 which is the required one for the organization. I'm connected to the company's VPN and at first I thought maybe this was the issue, but other members are using the exact same mule server config, build is run from the same branch, and they're also connected to the same VPN gateway, and for them it works but I keep getting the timeout whatever I try :(

I've tried extending timeouts on the db and in the config according to some forum suggestions, but nothing works and I ran out of ideas what to try next and where to look for the issue, so all help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT #1: I'm trying to setup the connection through AnyPointStudio hoping it will tell me more why the mule db connection is failing even though the db is accessible. But I encountered an issue - the connection itself is setup, but it seems like it doesn't recognize all schemas so I can't execute the query I need - is there any specific way I should configure the schema? I can't seem to find any option available for that

**SOLUTION**
It turned out to be an issue with a blocking port when an underlying http request was made out - not directly db related.
In AnyPoint I was finally able to connect as well but I needed to pass it the full name like [DB_NAME].[SCHEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME]

Comment: try to  find out if  there is a need to get ipwhitelisting

Comment: Thanks for your comment @satishchennupati. Any suggestions on how I should do this? I'm very new to mule :(. I tried googling it but most solutions are using mulesoft which I'm not - I'm just starting the server directly using $MULE_HOME/bin/mule - I suspect there's a config file somewhere where I can try to add the IP but I'm not clear where exactly. Otherwise if you know of a way to have some connection trace logs (like verbose wget f.ex.) - maybe that'll point me in the right direction

Comment: Hi @LisekKL. You are providing very little concrete details on the configurations and application so it is going to be difficult that you receive any concrete suggestions. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question and increase the chances of receiving answers.

Comment: Sorry everyone for the lack of details - the whole setup is on a company device separate from the one I'm using for Stack. Anyways - the issue got solved - the timeout was due to a port blocking issue set for the ip - so @satishchennupati you're hint helped - thanks :) As for AnyPoint - I needed to pass it the full name like [DB_NAME].[schema].[table_name].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION** It turned out to be an issue with a blocking port when an underlying http request was made out - not directly db related. In AnyPoint I was finally able to connect as well but I needed to pass it the full name like [DB_NAME].[SCHEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME]